# Cyclinder 2 misfire error code - 11 Dodge Journey 3.6L V6

Tags: coolant, misfire, thermostat, cylinder

2011 Dodge Journey Mainstreet 2wd 3.6L V6 100k miles

Check Engine Light on, first read Low Voltage

- replaced Battery

Check Engine Light came back on, 2nd read Cylinder 2 misfire, & Thermostat

- replaced coil & spark plug #2

Check Engline Light back on, 3rd read only mentioned the Cylinder 2 Misfire

- ???? Don't know what I should do next.

Some issues I've noticed:

- Heater doesn't fully heat.
- Burns fuel fast.
- Huge squeaky noise coming from a belt on passenger side under the coolant tank

I replaced the coolant tank about 6 months ago due to a leak, which I only noticed after my son moved my car and there was puddles everywhere. It did overheat a bit, as I was unaware there was an issue (no warning light from car given -_- )

I've checked hoses and wires and they all still seem pretty solid (not a mechanic here). I get my oil changed often, fluids changed and topped, I
 have the dealership check for maintenance repairs often too. So far though, I haven't had to do much. Now it's going down the drain. I will be having the internal thermostat replaced this weekend, and having the other spark plugs checked for any other faulty wires or whatever else. I just don't have hundreds of dollars to keep throwing at this issue. 
Any help and guidance is appreciated!!